# Polygon dissolve in DB

Tags: dissolve, db2

I have a polygon feature class with more than 100,000 polygons in DB2 table. I would like to dissolve them based on a single field to reduce the row numbers. Is there any commands / SQL in DB2 to dissolve these without using ArcGIS Desktop tool?

Answer (score 1):

You could try a variation on the union aggregate function. No idea if this has been implemted in DB2

[Aggregate functions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/edkatibah/2011/04/27/spatial-aggregates-in-sql-server-denali/)

Failing that if you can link up to QGIS then it has a default dissolve command which you can use on shape files if you have to as well so if you can't link if you could get the polygon into a shape format you could then perform the dissolve before returning the information to the database.

Warning dissolves on large datasets take a long time to process - I have had dissolves take 36 hours plus and that was for only 20,000 polygons so yours may take a significant longer amount of time.